# hasMany "through" relationship and a multiselect form

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers

I'm running cakephp 2.0.2 and I have the following relationships

```
    Category hasMany CategoryWork
    Work hasMany CategoryWork
    CategoryWork belongs to Category,Work
```

A classic hasMany through relationship per cake's documentation.

I have a work add/edit form with a select box allowing a user to select multiple categories. The problem I'm having is when a user edits an existing work, the associated categories aren't pre-selected.

I have the following code to populate the select box, which does in fact work:

```
$categoryWorks = $this->CategoryWork->Category->listCategories();
$this->set(compact('categoryWorks'));
```

Then my input field looks like this:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('CategoryWork', array('multiple' => true, 'label' => 'Categories')); ?>
```

This will populate the select field, but it does not pre-select it with the Work's associated categories.

So, I can fix this. I simply supply a selected option to the input call and I get my pre-selected categories. But I was expecting cakephp to be more magical for me :)

My theory is that cake is looking at the id of the CategoryWork rows returned from the work query and it's not matching up with the ids of the Categories populated in the dropdown. It needs to look at the category_id.

Thoughts on this? I feel I'm almost there, I'm just missing something to help cake do its thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check about hasAndBelongsToMany relationship ?

Basically it work like that : Category hasAndBelongsToMany Work using CategoryWork